# VS 2012 server explorer: unable to access table store

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am vs2012 premium and azure sdk for .net2.0. in the server explorer i am unable access the table storage, when accesing it is giving pop-up saying "unable to perform azure operation".
but i am able to access blob and table storage.
Any help would be appeciated.

Comment: What operation you're trying to perform? Are you connecting to table storage in local emulator or in cloud? Please provide more details.

Comment: @gaurav Mantri i am trying to table storage in both local emulater as well as in cloud but i am unable to do so. i am not performong any kind of operation